# Как получить PlaceholderText виджета QTextEdit в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5

Задача:

> Получить *PlaceholderText* виджета *QTextEdit*, для того,
>   чтобы в дальнейшем использовать эту информацию для "если", "то",
>   "иначе".

Не могу найти ничего. Может есть что-то
схожее с *toPlainText()* или *text()*, только для с *Placeholder*
текста?

---

Вопрос решён! Ответ: `textEdit.placeholderText()`  Благодарность @Alexander Chernin *)

Comment: Не очень понятно что вы хотите сделать. Приведите минимальный пример и объясните пожалуйста лучше суть проблемы.

Comment: Имеет. Для получения значения `textEdit.placeholderText()`, для установки `textEdit.setPlaceholderText(...)`

Comment: @Alexander Chernin, ты мой ангел хранитель! ;)

Comment: Рекомендую погуглить значение  `RTFM` :))